# How would you create and traverse a hash of hashes (of depth n), whereby the values at depth n are integers?

Tags: perl, hash, bioinformatics

I want to store DNA sequences of size n in the described data structure. Each hash could contain the keys C,G,A,T who will have hash values. These hash values will be the exact same kind of hashes - they will have four keys, C,G,A,T who will have hash values.

This structure is consistent for n levels of hashes. However, the last level of hashes will instead have integer values, which represent the count of the sequence from level 1 to level n.

Given the data ('CG', 'CA', 'TT', 'CG'), indicating that the sequences CG, CA, and TT occurred twice, once, and once.  For this data, the depth would be 2.

This would produce a hash:
%root = ( 'C' => { 'G' => 2, 'A' => 1}, 'T' => {'T' => 1 })

How would one create this hash from the data?

Comment: sry i really don't get what you want. also there is no distinct question!

Comment: Are you trying to construct a radix search trie?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need is a function `get_node($tree, 'C', 'G')` returns a reference to the hash element for "CG". Then you can just increment the referenced scalar.

```
sub get_node {
   my $p = \shift;
   $p = \( ($$p)->{$_} ) for @_;
   return $p;
}

my @seqs = qw( CG CA TT CG );

my $tree;
++${ get_node($tree, split //) } for @seqs;
```

The thing is, this function already exists as [Data::Diver](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Data%3a%3aDiver)'s `DiveRef`.

```
use Data::Diver qw( DiveRef );

my @seqs = qw( CG CA TT CG );

my $tree = {};
++${ DiveRef($tree, split //) } for @seqs;
```

In both case,

```
use Data::Dumper qw( Dumper );
print(Dumper($tree));
```

prints

```
$VAR1 = {
          'T' => {
                   'T' => 1
                 },
          'C' => {
                   'A' => 1,
                   'G' => 2
                 }
        };
```

Answer (score 2):

The following should work:

```
use Data::Dumper;

my %data;
my @sequences = qw(CG CG CA TT);

foreach my $sequence (@sequences) {
    my @vars = split(//,$sequence);
    $data{$vars[0]} = {} if (!exists($data{$vars[0]}));
    my $startref = $data{$vars[0]};
    for(my $i = 1; $i < $#vars; $i++) {
    $startref->{$vars[$i]} = {} if (!exists($startref->{$vars[$i]}));
    $startref = $startref->{$vars[$i]};
    }
    $startref->{$vars[$#vars]}++;
}

print Dumper(\%data);
```

Produces:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'T' => {
                   'T' => 1
                 },
          'C' => {
                   'A' => 1,
                   'G' => 2
                 }
        };
```

Comment: You can say `$hash{key} //= {}` instead of `$hash{key} = {} if !exists $hash{key}`.  It's not exactly the same (since it checks if `defined $hash{key}` rather than `exists`), but the main advantage of `exists` over `defined` (as I understand it) is that `//=` will fail if `$hash{key}` is defined but has a value `undef`.  I find `//=` easier to read. YMMV.